# 'Yearling' badge awarded three times in five days

Tags: bug

I'm not sure if this is intended behaviour or a bug, but this notification has come up three times this week. I've definitely only earned 200 reputation in one calendar year (or, at best, in two separate 365-day periods, one of which just began).

It seems to just award me this badge, both on the main SE and on meta, every time my reputation crosses a multiple of 200.

Seems kind of weird. Does anyone know what's going on here?

[image]

Comment: It seems like the triggers can activate retroactively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your reputation has recently shot up this month from 111 to 666 (as of now) that's expected because you have over 3 x 200 reputation so you've become eligible for three badges. You've now been a member six years so you could get another three fairly quickly if it increases to 1200. The following answer explains it further:

[How does the Yearling badge now work over multi years?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237083/203972)

But I've seen the same thing asked a few times before and had the same myself on other sites so it's expected behaviour not a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The formula in the link doesn't match the description (I have been an *active* member for less than a month) but I suppose they don't want to put effort into more-accurate participation tracking.

Comment: Yup, confirmed -- I have now apparently packed four years of activity into one week.